# How to find help on PyQt5 classes?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Where can I find details on a specific class of PyQt5. Surely I can use the **help(module)** command within Python IDLE but it doesn't provide all necessary information.

For example: How do I find about all possible functions and their respective arguments available to `QWidget` class from `PyQt5.QtWidgets` module?

Comment: [Qt5 Docs: All Classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html).

Comment: Ya. This provides with most of the required information. Thank you

Comment: @ekhumoro Those doesn't provide Python documentation. What if I am not familiar with C++?

Comment: @SantoshKumar. Same answer. You don't really need to know C++ at all. It doesn't take much effort to translate into Python, because the APIs are very similar. For the specific differences, you can use `help` and/or tab-completion in an interactive session, as well as experimenting with live objects (which is probably most useful of all). Also, the [pyqt source packages](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) contain dozens of working examples that have been ported from the Qt docs.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [API reference](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/index.html), but the actual class description pages only link to the respective C++ class page. I'm afraid that is your best option for now, until the PyQt maintainers update their documentation (which is based on the C++ docs anyway).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little buried, but there is Qt for Python / PyQt5 / PySide2 documentation online:

- [Main Documentation Page](https://doc.qt.io/)
- [Main Wiki Page (how to get started, what to download, etc.](https://wiki.qt.io/Main)

Examples:

- [The PySide2.QtCore.Qt module](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/Qt.html)
- [The "All Classes" page for Qt5, accessed through a Qt 5.13.0 link currently](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html#)